# Find the expression for the sum of this power series: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(n+3)!} $

Tags: power-series

I'm a bit stuck on this problem. I supposed to find an expression for the sum of this power series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(n+3)!} $$

I know I should use $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} $$

But then I get confused, and I don't how I shall proceed to find the answer.

Comment: **Hint:**  You know that $e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$.  What is $\sum\limits_{n=\color{red}{3}}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ where we changed the lower limit to $n=3$ instead?  How does this compare to $e^x$?  How does this compare to your series?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I could write $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+3}}{(n+3)!}=e^x$ and then mulitply by $1/x^3$ on both sides getting $\frac{e^x}{x^3}=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+3)!}$. I'm I thinking right?

Comment: Almost... multiplying by $\frac{1}{x^3}$ is certainly going to be useful here.  But what you wrote isn't equal to $e^x$.  Maybe for intuition try writing it out some terms.  $e^x = 1+\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\color{blue}{\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\dots}$.  On the other hand you have $\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = \color{blue}{\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\dots}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm sorry, but I have a hard time understanding. I see now that what i wrote was wrong, I would have to write $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-3}}{(n-3)!}$ for it to be equal to $e^x$. But that confuses me even more :(

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you mean now (or I hope so). So $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{x^2}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Then must $e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ But then I find it hard to proceed. I'm sorry for asking so much. I'm just curious when it comes to how you would solve it.

Comment: Ohh. I find out everything right after I write it down here in the comments. Okay, I think I got it now. Thank you for the help by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(n+3)!}=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-3}}{n!}=x^{-3}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}=x^{-3}(e^x-\frac{x^0}{0!}-\frac{x^1}{1!}-\frac{x^2}{2!})=\frac{e^x}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2x}$$
I believe that I've done everything correctly.

Comment: I get a bit lost when it comes to your fourth expression when you get rid of the sigma. Is not $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}= \frac{x^3}{3!}+...$ Where does $e^x$ come from?

Comment: $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^n/n!}$ therefore $\sum_{n=3}^\infty{x^n/n!}$ is equal to $e^x$ minus the first three terms which are $x^0/0!$, $x^1/1!$, $x^2/2!$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!